# when to use transformable data type versus relationship core data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, data-modeling

This is a newbie type question, but I am stuck on how to do this within the context of Core Data in iOS.

I have a data type I want to use called Measurement which consists of a unit (string) and a value (double). I have another class PhysicalAttributes which has a number of attributes some of which are primitive data types and some (most) which should be of type Measurement.

In Core Data, I made an entity called Measurement and an entity called PhysicalAttributes.

If I were not using Core Data, I would have a class like:

```
@interface PhysicalAttributes : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) Measurement *height ;
@property (nonatomic) Measurement *weight ;

// etc.

@end
```

But I cannot determine if in Core Data I should use relationships called height, weight, etc. or use a transformable data type and model it that way. It doesn't feel right to call it a relationship since Measurement is really a data type.

All the examples I can find of using core data don't really give examples of something like the above.

Any help/pointers appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at apple's sample code:- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want Measurement? Maybe as an abstract class or a protocol, but you probably want classes for Weight and Height, otherwise, the possible types inside Measurement are going to get really ugly.

I agree with you about it making you feel dirty to use a relationship for something like this, but, the other way to look at it is these measurements are probably being captured at some point in time, so you could add a timestamp too.

Martin Fowler's book [Analysis Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201895420) discusses this at some length and comes down on the side of doing classes (which is correct) for these things.

Comment: Good point, but it still begs the question. If there were classes for Weight, Height, etc. and I wanted them in an aggregate class (PhysicalAttributes), I would still either be faced with using transformable data type or using relationships. So, the original question still stands as to the 'proper' way to model this using Core Data. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want them in an aggregate? I don't see how the question stands. If you make a class for grouping some attributes, then the base class (e.g. Patient) has a 1:1 to PhysicalAttributes and that contains 1:1s to Weight and Height.

Comment: If you follow the temporal model I mentioned, you would have height and weight recordings at different points in time, and then you would probably add a method in a category for currentWeight/Height that just fetched the most recent reading.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my example made my question clear. The issue boils down to the best way to model an abstract data type within the confines of Core Data. Assume for the sake of the question that Measurement is an abstract data type and that multiple classes want to use that data type. In the object model, this is straightforward. However, within Core Data, I am stuck with base data types (int, boolean, etc.), relationships, or transformable data types (storing it in core data as a blob and transforming it into the data type within the app). ...post continued below...

Comment: So assuming I need that data type (for whatever reason), the question is how to best model that in Core Data. Does that make sense? A relationship seems awkward especially since Core Data seems to want an inverse relationship, but with a blob I lose the ability to query directly.

Comment: Yeah I knew that was what you were asking, and that is a good question. AFAIC, this is one of CD's remaining Achilles' Heels: Hibernate does this pretty well. If you have to do stuff like this in CD, you need to write code in awakeFromInsert and FromFetch to deblob the data into whatever it is you are treating as a type in the middle layer. But, I thought that what I was saying was for this case, I don't see what has to be blobbed. You can do it with relations.